# How do I sum tuples in a list where the first value is the same?

Tags: python

I have a list of stocks and positions as tuples. Positive for buy, negative for sell. Example:

```
p = [('AAPL', 50), ('AAPL', -50), ('RY', 100), ('RY', -43)]
```

How can I sum the positions of stocks, to get the current holdings?

```
result = [('AAPL', 0), ('RY', 57)]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this? You can read about [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> testDict = defaultdict(int)
>>> p = [('AAPL', 50), ('AAPL', -50), ('RY', 100), ('RY', -43)]
>>> for key, val in p:
        testDict[key] += val


>>> testDict.items()
[('AAPL', 0), ('RY', 57)]
```

Comment: How about that indeed! Thanks very much, worked perfectly and now I have some reading to do as well.

Comment: `collections` library is full of gems. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that doesn't involve importing:

```
>>> p = [('AAPL', 50), ('AAPL', -50), ('RY', 100), ('RY', -43)]
>>> d = {x:0 for x,_ in p}
>>> for name,num in p: d[name] += num
...
>>> Result = map(tuple, d.items())
>>> Result
[('AAPL', 0), ('RY', 57)]
>>>
```

Note this is for Python 2.x.  In 3.x, you'll need to do: `Result = list(map(tuple, d.items()))`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [2]: from collections import Counter

In [3]: c = Counter()

In [4]: for k, v in p:
   ...:     c[k] += v
   ...:     
In [5]: c
Out[5]: Counter({'AAPL': 0, 'RY': 57})
```

Then you can call the `most_common` method of `Counter` objects to get a list of tuples sorted by the values in descending order.

```
In [5]: c.most_common()
Out[5]: [('RY', 57), ('AAPL', 0)]
```

In case you need to sort tuples by their first elements, use `sorted(c.items())`:

```
In [6]: sorted(c.items())
Out[6]: [('AAPL', 0), ('RY', 57)]
```

Answer (score 0):

without any explicit loops:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> p = [('AAPL', 50), ('AAPL', -50), ('RY', 100), ('RY', -43)]
>>> map(lambda g: (g[0], sum(map(itemgetter(1), g[1]))),
...     groupby(sorted(p), itemgetter(0)))
[('AAPL', 0), ('RY', 57)]
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if the stocks are contiguous; you'd need to sort by the keyfunc otherwise.  Actually, come to think of it, I think it reads a little better without two maps: `[(k, sum(map(itemgetter(1), g))) for k,g in groupby(p, itemgetter(0))]`.