# Finding Duplicate element in list of tuples

Tags: python

In the List of tuples, add the 2nd element if the first and last element matches with the other tuples.

```
    p =[(u'basic', 7698, '01-2017'),
    (u'basic', 7685, '01-2017'),
    (u'Gross', 4875.0, u'01-2017'),
    (u'Gross', 4875.0, u'01-2017')]
```

And the output should be like

```
    [(u'basic',15383,'01-2017'),(u'Gross', 9750.0, u'01-2017')]
```

I'm trying to do this way

```
   o=[]        
   for i in p:
     if i[2] not in o:
        o.append(i[2])
     if i[0] not in o:
        o.append(i[0])
   count +=i[1]
   o.append(count)
```

my o/p:

```
   ['01-2017', 'basic', u'Gross', 53050.0, 4875.0]
```

Comment: I've not used it, but this sounds like a job for pandas.

Comment: Describe your problem in the question, not the headline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sum tuples in a list where the first value is the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194712/how-do-i-sum-tuples-in-a-list-where-the-first-value-is-the-same)

Comment: What have you tried so far? We will not think for you. Please try yourself, and if you have problems, post your code and we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to handle this. Use the first and last elements of the tuple as a key and the second as the value, which is accumulated by addition:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [(u'basic', 7698, '01-2017'),
     (u'basic', 7685, '01-2017'),
     (u'Gross', 4875.0, u'01-2017'),
     (u'Gross', 4875.0, u'01-2017')]

d = defaultdict(int)
for t in l:
    d[(t[0], t[-1])] += t[1]

# create list of tuples from the defaultdict values
result = [(k[0], d[k], k[1]) for k in d]

>>> print(result)
[(u'basic', 15383, '01-2017'), (u'Gross', 9750.0, u'01-2017')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [(u'basic', 7698, '01-2017'),
     (u'basic', 7685, '01-2017'),
     (u'Gross', 4875.0, u'01-2017'),
     (u'Gross', 4875.0, u'01-2017'),
     (u'basic', 7685, '01-2017'),]

# make a list of tuples of 1st and 3rd elements
r = [(x, z) for x, y, z in l]

# this is based on
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list
r_sorted = [(y,x[1]) for (y, x) in sorted(zip(r, l), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]

# this is based on
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194712/how-do-i-sum-tuples-in-a-list-where-the-first-value-is-the-same
# as per @Idles dublication alert
testDict = defaultdict(int)
for key, val in r_sorted:
    testDict[key] += val

print(testDict.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this :

```
from itertools import groupby

p =[(u'basic', 7698, '01-2017'),
    (u'basic', 7685, '01-2017'),
    (u'Gross', 4875.0, u'01-2017'),
    (u'Gross', 4875.0, u'01-2017')]

[(grp[0], sum(val[1] for val in vals), grp[1]) 
    for grp, vals in groupby(p, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))]

# [('basic', 15383, '01-2017'), ('Gross', 9750.0, '01-2017')]
```