# Convert the list of tuples into set with its corresponding sum efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have list like this:

```
x = [(('abc', 'def'), 1), (('foo', 'bar'), 0), (('def', 'abc'), 3)]
```

I want to make a list which contains unique elements with its corresponding sum in which the order should not matter.I want list like this:

```
[(('abc', 'def'), 4),  (('foo', 'bar'), 0)]
```

What is the efficient way to do this in python?

It is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194712/how-do-i-sum-tuples-in-a-list-where-the-first-value-is-the-same) as I am asking about tuple of tuple in which the first parameter is unordered.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Please read the question again. I have made the necessary changes. The question is actually different. In my question, the tuple's order should not matter.

Comment: I don't see the difference. Can you elaborate? The accepted answer from the duplicate produces exactly the output you want.

Comment: @Aran-Fey In my question it is the tuple of tuple with first parameter of tuple is unordered

Comment: Deleted my comments. This has been edited and now looks like a duplicate. The initial question was for a count of duplicates, not a sum.

Comment: @vaultah Please reopen the question as I have edited it and the edited question is different and I have explained that in comments.

Comment: I mean, that's a minor difference. All you need to do is to sort the tuples first or convert them to frozensets. I think it'll suffice to add a 2nd question to the dupe list.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I want to ask that question. How to do that? I am having tuple of tuple. Can you please explain what I can do in this case?

Comment: @MatthewStory Please read the question again as I have edited the question.

Comment: Use the default dict from https://stackoverflow.com/q/18194712/2301450 and use a `frozenset` as the key: `defaultdict_[frozenset(tuple_)] += value`

Comment: @Aran-Fey As you have edited the question. Can you please reopen it as it is the mixture of two or more questions. It is not duplicate.

Comment: @MatthewStory Can you please reopen the question and explain it in  answer clearly.

Comment: I can't re-open this for you. But if @Aray-Fey determines it should be re-opened I would be happy to provide you with an answer.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Please consider the question again and reopen it. Matthew Story is ready to answer the question.

Comment: @vaultah Please consider the question again and reopen it. It is edited and  Matthew Story is ready to answer the question.

Comment: I've reopened the question. I had better see a good answer down there soon, or I'm going to regret this decision.

Comment: @MatthewStory The question is reopened. Can you please answer the question now.

Comment: lol @Aran-Fey ... I didn't mean to imply that I thought the question *should* be re-opened. I will do my best to do you proud though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for k,v in x:
    c[tuple(sorted(k))] += v

print(c)
# Counter({('abc', 'def'): 4, ('bar', 'foo'): 0})

print (list(c.items()))
# [(('abc', 'def'), 4), (('bar', 'foo'), 0)]
```

Comment: use `c[k] + v` instead of `.update`. Don't use `.update` for a single key-value pair. Note, this (very inefficiently) creates a useless dictionary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you explain it more or if possible can you please write the answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Thanks for your suggestion. Modified accordingly.